# can I link a portable washer to 'conventional' laundry hook up?

Tags: clothes-washer

seeing that my leasing agent is putting up my rent per month by over $50 and no option to move, I'm thinking of ways to cut cost - one thing is to stop renting a washer for $22.50 a month and just buy a unit. I am considering buying a portable washer (something like this: http://www.walmart.com/ip/Haier-1.5-cu-ft-Portable-Washer/36758182#about), but I'm trying to figure out if I HAVE to use this next to my kitchen sink, or whether I could just link it to the conventional laundry hookup that's already in my apartment...any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a decent used washer?  Around here they're all over the place for less than what a portable would cost.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the manufacturer, but if you're willing to wash in cold water you should be able to use the "real" laundry hookup.

Looking for used machines is definitely worth considering, though.